# How can I annotate two different Cloud Armor BackendConfigs to of a service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-armor

I have two Cloud Armor policies.
Policy "A" is allowing our office network to connect to specific services.
Policy "B" is allowing a customer to a service to consume an API.

I can not add the rule of Policy "B" to Policy "A" because then the rule (the customers ip) would've access to all services where Policy "A" is applied to. Therefore I separated it off to the a standalone Policy "B".

So I have now two different BackendConfig resources. One referencing to Policy "A" and one to Policy "B".

The next step I took was to somehow apply **both** cloud armor backend configs to one specific service. The office network should've access to that services **plus** the IP of our customer.
This is how I thought it might work:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default":{"policy-a-cloud-armor-backend-config","policy-b-cloud-armor-backend-config"}}'
```

Unfortunately this does **not** work. In the policy panel in GCP the following warning appears:

```
This policy has not been applied to any targets yet, so the policy will not affect any traffic.
```

Any idea how I can make this exclusive access possible?

Comment: Could it be you're trying to apply Cloud armor security policy to the service type NodePort while working with Ingress?

Comment: The annotation syntax does not look consistent with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig#associating_a_service_port_with_a_backendconfig): `'{"ports": {"http":"config-http", "http2" :"config-http2"}, "default": "config-default"}';` , the field `ports` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notification `This policy has not been applied to any targets yet, so the policy will not affect any traffic` indicates that a security policy is not bound to any of targets via backend configuration and annotations.

The annotation syntax does not look consistent with the documentation: the field `ports` is missing. It should be like this:

```
{"ports": {"http":"config-http", "http2" :"config-http2"}, "default": "config-default"}
```

See [Associating a Service port with a BackendConfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig#associating_a_service_port_with_a_backendconfig)

It is hardly possible to apply two different security policies to the same set like service/port.

As a workaround, you can try an additional service with a special security policy that includes rules for both clients.